# How to split 1 dataframe into two dataframes based on column1's value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've looked through several other stackoverflow questions similar to this, but couldn't find what I am looking for

For example, if I have a data frame with 2 columns

```
TrueFalse | Numbers
-------------------
True      | 1
False     | 5
True      | 1
True      | 1
False     | 2
False     | 2
True      | 3
```

I want to figure out a way to take that example "dataframe" and turn it into two separate dataframes, so if the TrueFalse value equals "true", the whole row is copied to df1, if the TrueFalse value equals "false", the whole row is copied to df2. And then try to count how many of these rows have a value of 'True'.

So after the python script runs, i would have a new dataframe that looks like:

```
TrueFalse | Numbers
-------------------
True      | 1
True      | 1
True      | 1
True      | 3
```

and

```
TrueFalse | Numbers
-------------------
False     | 5
False     | 2
False     | 2
```

I've tried what was found in other stackoverflow questions and several websites but if for example i do.

```
for row in df:
   if df['TrueFalse'][row:row+1] == 'True':
      df1.append(df[row])
```

I haven't done Python in a long while and I know that code above doesn't work, but I have no clue how to make it work. Any help/pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the following:

```
df_true = df[df['TrueFalse'] == True]
df_false = df[df['TrueFalse'] == False]
```

This will copy all of the dataframe based on the value of 'TrueFalse'.

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Comment: From a quick look at the documentation, I think you'd do it like this: `df_true.mode()['Numbers'][0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = df[df.TrueFalse]
df2 = df[~df.TrueFalse]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
df1 = df[df['TrueFalse'] == True]
....
```